# Is there such a thing as a weighted multiple regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

I'm new to linear algebra, but I know how multiple linear regressions work.  What I want to do is something slightly different.

As an example, let's say that I have a list of nutrients I want to get every day.  Say I have a list of foods, and I want to know how much of each food to eat to get the best fit for my nutrition plan.  Assume I'm fine with using a linear model.

However, some nutrients are more important than others.  The errors on protein and calcium might be equal in a typical linear regression, but that's no use.  Protein has higher priority than calcium (in this model), so I'd want a model that is better fitting to the higher priority points than to the lower ones.

I tried putting weights on the error function, and I end up with a matrix of matrices.  At that point, I'm not sure if I'm minimising for the weights or for the coefficients on the nutrients.  I think both, but I wasn't sure how to minimise for both at the same time.

Is it possible to solve this with linear algebra, or does this require some numerical approximation solution?

Comment: yes, see weighted linear regression @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Weighted_linear_least_squares

Answer (score 0):

So here is my understanding of what you have in mind. Let $X_i$ ($i=1...N$) represent the total number of units for nutrient $i$. Each nutrient has a weight $w_i$. Therefore, your objective function is $\sum_{i=1}^N w_iX_i$.

But, you don't choose nutrients directly, you choose foods. Let food be represented by the subscript $j$,   $j=1...J$,  Each food $j$ is associated with a set of nutrients. In particular, suppose that 1 unit of each food has $m_{ij}$ units of nutrient $i$. Therefore, if you purchase one unit of food, your objective function increases by $\sum w_im_{ij}$.

Finally, let $F_j$ represent the amount of food $j$ purchases (or consumed). Then your objective is to choose a consumption set of foods  {$F_j$} to maximize your objective function.

$max_{\{F_j\}} \sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{i=1}^N F_j w_im_{ij}$

Perhaps subject to some budget constraint?